# What's wrong about this Format.ps1xml file? "A node is missing from TableControl, ListControl, WideControl, CustomControl"

Tags: xml, powershell, formatting

I tried to write a Format.ps1xml file, but when loading it, I get a very unspecific error message:

```
Import-Module : Errors occurred while loading the format data file:
Test.Format.ps1xml, Error at XPath /Configuration/ViewDefinitions/View[1] in file Test.Format.ps1xml: A node is missing from TableControl, ListControl, WideControl, CustomControl.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module ./PSSourcegraph.psd1 -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I read through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg581019(v=vs.85).aspx) of every node multiple times and I don't see what node is missing. Specifically the documention for `ListControl` says:

> This element must contain only a single child element.

Weirdly, the error goes away if I remove the `EntrySelectedBy` tag.

Here's the Format.ps1xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>MyType</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>MyTypeName1</TypeName>
                <TypeName>MyTypeName2</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <ListControl>
                <ListEntries>
                    <ListEntry>
                        <EntrySelectedBy>
                            <TypeName>MyTypeName1</TypeName>
                        </EntrySelectedBy>
                        <ListItems>
                            <ListItem>
                                <PropertyName>myProp</PropertyName>
                            </ListItem>
                        </ListItems>
                    </ListEntry>
                </ListEntries>
            </ListControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `xml` fan and this is too long to be a comment.  If it does not help I'll delete myself.

**Edit** Did miss the selection process.  Edit based on comment.  I think you are missing the `<SelectionSets>` & `<SelectionSet>` nodes.  Then you can select selectionset, then select your entry with `<EntrySelectedBy>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <SelectionSets>
        <SelectionSet>
            <Name>MyTypes</Name>
            <Types>
                <TypeName>MyTypeName1</TypeName>
                <TypeName>MyTypeName2</TypeName>
            </Types>
        </SelectionSet>
    </SelectionSets>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>children</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <SelectionSetName>MyTypes</SelectionSetName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <ListControl>
                <ListEntries>
                    <ListEntry>
                        <EntrySelectedBy>
                            <TypeName>MyTypeName1</TypeName>
                        </EntrySelectedBy>
                        <ListItems>
                            <ListItem>
                                <PropertyName>myProp</PropertyName>
                            </ListItem>
                        </ListItems>
                    </ListEntry>
                </ListEntries>
            </ListControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: How does this select `myProp` only for `MyTypeName1`?

Comment: @felixfbecker good point.  It does not, see my different approach.